# Where to download large data set sample for Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, dump

is there any place where I can download a large data set of some dummy or real-life (anonymized) data for practicing performance tuning in Oracle?

I have only found StackOverflow dumps - and I am already downloading those (tho they allegedly are for MySQL only)...

Do you have any idea where I could find such dumps?

Thank you for any help

EDIT:

Ok I found some data sources worth a try ...

- https://openlibrary.org/developers/dumps
- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/bulk-download-facility
- https://www.yelp.com/dataset/download (non-commercial use only)

Answer (score 3):

Any data set anywhere can be used for this in Oracle.

The easiest types of data to load into Oracle are 'delimited' - the most famous of which is known as 'CSV'

You can then build a [SQLLoader](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/yes-sqlloader-is-faster-at-loading-records/) scenario or [External Table](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/08/loading-data-via-external-tables-fast/) to load a massive amount of data - hundreds of gigabytes or more, OR you can use a GUI like Oracle SQL Developer to load the rows into a new or existing table.

[I talk about both approaches here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/) It says 'Excel' but CSV works much the same way.

I've used my own data for this. I've gotten dumps from Twitter (all my Tweets), Untappd (all my beers), Strava (all my activities).

I've used public data for this - [NHL stats](http://%20http://hsp.flyershistory.com) (35,000 rows), Airports, etc. Just google 'open data' and look for CSV.

Of course I'd be remiss not to mention our own public sample data sets. We make these available on [Github](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas).

Customer Orders is the newest one (2019)
[image]

Comment: Also, i'm pretty sure the stackoverflow dumps are for SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: thx for your reply.. I know any data can be used for any database buddy :) the point is - I don't have the data ... that's what I am looking for ...  35k rows is not really a big dump .. I am talking about hundreds of millions of records :)  GBs of data .. the one you shared is a tiny blog database (no offense) .. anyway I will try the "open data" tip for googling

Comment: i'm not your buddy, pal :) GBs of data isn't a lot of data either. there are many, many LARGE data sets out there, pick one. also, you don't need a ton of data to practice oracle sql tuning

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the (free) data generator *and* load generator tool SwingBench by Dominic Giles:

http://www.dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html

It can create an OLTP schema and run a bunch of transactions and queries at the concurrency level you specify. Also you can create a "TPC-DS like" schema for data warehouse query testing (and it even supports running some transactions on the DW schema if you want to).